# Is it ok to run the docker container as a non-root user but with sudo privileges?

Tags: docker, security, root, sudo, privileges

It’s pretty well known that docker containers have to be run as non-root users. But **is it ok** if the container run as **non-root user but with `sudo` privileges**?

Example:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt-get install sudo

# A lot of work ...

RUN addgroup --gid 1000 app && adduser --uid 1000 --ingroup app --disabled-password app
RUN adduser app sudo
RUN echo '%app ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
USER 1000

ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  This makes it very slightly easier to not accidentally break your container, but if there's an actual security bug in your application, having to prepend `sudo` to commands isn't really going to slow an attacker down.

Since a container only runs one process, and since it's straightforward to switch users in a Dockerfile if needed, there's not usually a need for `sudo` in Docker at all.